# 2D Vector class

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, coordinate-system

As part of a game engine I am creating, I am in the process of writing a bunch of math classes (vector2/3/4, matrix2/3/4, and quaternions to start with).

`Vec2` class:

```
import math
import random

class Vec2(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        self._x = float(new_x)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, new_y):
        self._y = float(new_y)

    def __add__(self, other):
        types = (int, float)
        if isinstance(self, types):
            return Vec2(self + other.x, self + other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, types):
            return Vec2(self.x + other, self.y + other)
        else:
            return Vec2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    def __div__(self, other):
        types = (int, float)
        if isinstance(self, types):
            self = Vec2(self, self)
        elif isinstance(other, types):
            other = Vec2(other, other)
        x = self.x / other.x
        y = self.y / other.y
        return Vec2(x, y)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        types = (int, float)
        if isinstance(self, types):
            return Vec2(self * other.x, self * other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, types):
            return Vec2(self.x * other, self.y * other)
        else:
            return Vec2(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vec2(-self.x, -self.y)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Vec2(self.x + other, self.y + other)

    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return Vec2(other/self.x, other/self.y)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Vec2(other * self.x, other * self.y)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Vec2(other - self.x, other - self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return "Vec2: ({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        types = (int, float)
        if isinstance(self, types):
            return Vec2(self - other.x, self - other.y)
        elif isinstance(other, types):
            return Vec2(self.x - other, self.y - other)
        else:
            return Vec2(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)

    def ceil(self):
        return Vec2(math.ceil(self.x), math.ceil(self.y))

    def floor(self):
        return Vec2(math.floor(self.x), math.floor(self.y))

    def get_data(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)    

    def inverse(self):
        return Vec2(1.0/self.x, 1.0/self.y)

    def length(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.square_length())

    def normalize(self):
        length = self.length()
        if length == 0.0:
            return Vec2(0, 0)
        return Vec2(self.x/length, self.y/length)

    def round(self):
        return Vec2(round(self.x), round(self.y))

    def square_length(self):
        return (self.x * self.x) + (self.y * self.y)

    """
    def transform(self, matrix):#mat2, mat2d, mat3, mat4
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cross(cls, a, b):
        z = (a.x * b.y) - (a.y * b.x)
        return Vec3(0, 0, z)
    """

    @classmethod
    def distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.length()

    @classmethod
    def dot(self, a, b):
        return (a.x * b.x) + (a.y * b.y)

    @classmethod
    def equals(cls, a, b, tolerance=0.0):
        diff = a - b
        dx = math.fabs(diff.x)
        dy = math.fabs(diff.y)
        if dx <= tolerance * max(1, math.fabs(a.x), math.fabs(b.x)) and \
           dy <= tolerance * max(1, math.fabs(a.y), math.fabs(b.y)):
            return True
        return False

    @classmethod
    def max(cls, a, b):
        x = max(a.x, b.x)
        y = max(a.y, b.y)
        return Vec2(x, y)

    @classmethod
    def min(cls, a, b):
        x = min(a.x, b.x)
        y = min(a.y, b.y)
        return Vec2(x, y)

    @classmethod
    def mix(cls, a, b, t):
        return a * t + b * (1-t)

    @classmethod
    def random(cls):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        return Vec2(x, y)

    @classmethod
    def square_distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.square_length()
```

And here is how it can currently be used in my engine:

```
from pyorama.math3d.vec2 import Vec2

a = Vec2(1, 2.5)
b = Vec2(5, -1)
print a+1, 1+a, a+b, b+a
print a-1, 1-a, a-b, b-a
print a*2, 2*a, a*b, b*a
print a/3, 3/a, a/b, b/a
print -a, -b

a.x = 3.0
a.y = 4
print type(a.x), type(a.y), a

print a.ceil()
print a.floor()
print a.get_data()
print a.inverse()
print a.length()
print a.normalize()
print a.round()
print a.square_length()
#print a.transform(None)#not implemented
#print Vec2.cross(a, b)#not implemented
print Vec2.distance(a, b)
print Vec2.dot(a, b)
print Vec2.equals(a, b, tolerance=200)
print Vec2.max(a, b)
print Vec2.min(a, b)
print Vec2.mix(a, b, 0.5)
print Vec2.random()
print Vec2.square_distance(a, b)
```

My major concern is whether or not it would be better to organize the code as it is currently, in a module, in a purely OOP manner (without `@classmethod`) or in a `@classmethod` only manner. Here are the advantages as I see them:

- My current organization is inconsistent as it mixes instance (when there is one `Vec2` argument) and class methods (when there are two `Vec2` arguments) together. This might be confusing for new users, but it could make writing math out in code much easier.
- A `vec2` module instead could lead to better performance (since I am not creating a bunch of `Vec2` objects and would be returning tuples/lists instead). However, I would not have any niceties such as operator overloading.
- Avoiding `@classmethod` would make the code more consistent and could allow chaining, but it may be difficult to read `a.dot(b)` versus `Vec2.dot(a, b)`.
- Using only `@classmethod` would make the code more consistent in usage (everything is `Vec2.something()` but chaining operations would be impossible. Operator overloading could also be annoying to deal with.

Another minor issue I have is with the names of my functions. Is it better to abbreviate the names and replace `Vec2.distance(a, b)` with `Vec2.dist(a, b)` in order to be consistent with the abbreviated name of the class or should I leave them spelled out instead (and perhaps rename `Vec2` to `Vector2`)? I was also not sure if is it acceptable to use built-in function names in my custom class (such as `len` or `round`) as while I am not polluting the namespace and I cannot think of adequate alternative names, it can lead to improper syntax highlighting.

I know I am asking a lot of probably trivial stylistic questions, but I would greatly appreciate any advice!

---

Following @ChrisR's helpful idea of creating base vector and matrix classes using numpy that can be extended, I have created a `Vec` class and a `Vec2` class. Here are both of those classes as they currently stand:

**vec.py:**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import random

class Vec(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return Vec(self.data + other.data)
        return Vec(self.data + other)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return Vec(other + self.data)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return Vec(self.data - other.data)
        return Vec(self.data - other)

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return Vec(other - self.data)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return Vec(self.data * other.data)
        return Vec(self.data * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Vec(other * self.data)

    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Vec):
            return Vec(self.data / other.data)
        return Vec(self.data / other)

    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return Vec(other / self.data)

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vec(-self.data)

    def __pos__(self):
        return Vec(+self.data)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return np.array_equal(self.data, other.data)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() < other.square_length()

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() <= other.square_length()

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() > other.square_length()

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.square_length() >= other.square_length()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def __str__(self):
        return np.array_str(self.data)

    def ceil(self):
        return Vec(np.ceil(self.data))

    def floor(self):
        return Vec(np.floor(self.data))

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def inverse(self):
        return Vec(1.0/self.data)

    def length(self):
        return float(np.linalg.norm(self.data))

    def normalize(self):
        length = self.length()
        if length == 0.0:
            return Vec(np.zeros(self.data.shape()))
        return Vec(self.data/length)

    def round(self, decimal=0):
        return Vec(np.round(self.data, decimal))

    def square_length(self):
        return float(np.sum(np.square(self.data)))

    @classmethod
    def distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.length()

    @classmethod
    def dot(self, a, b):
        return Vec(np.dot(a.data, b.data))

    @classmethod
    def equals(cls, a, b, tolerance=0.0):
        diffs = np.fabs((a - b).data)
        pairs = zip(list(np.fabs(a.data)), list(np.fabs(b.data)))
        tolerance_calcs = [tolerance * max(1, a_val, b_val) for (a_val, b_val) in pairs]
        tests = [d <= t for (d, t) in zip(diffs, tolerance_calcs)]
        return all(tests)

    @classmethod
    def max_components(cls, a, b):
        return Vec(np.maximum(a.data, b.data))

    @classmethod
    def min_components(cls, a, b):
        return Vec(np.minimum(a.data, b.data))

    @classmethod
    def mix(cls, a, b, t):
        return a*(1-t) + b*t

    @classmethod
    def random(cls, n):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        return Vec(np.random.rand((n)))

    @classmethod
    def square_distance(cls, a, b):
        c = b - a
        return c.square_length()
```

**vec2.py:**

```
from vec import Vec

import math
import numpy as np
import random

class Vec2(Vec):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self._x = float(x)
        self._y = float(y)
        super(Vec2, self).__init__(np.array([x, y], dtype=np.float32))

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, new_x):
        self._x = float(new_x)
        self.data[0] = self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, new_y):
        self._y = float(new_y)
        self.data[1] = self._y
```

This is definitely a lot more convenient, although the numpy arithmetic leads to some interesting floating point rounding errors. I renamed `min/max` to `min_components/max_components` to clear up any confusion and added > and < comparisons that compare based on vector magnitude.

However, this does introduce a new issue. One is the random function in `Vec2` needs to be called like `Vec2.random(2)` which is ugly. In that case, should I even implement a random function in the base `Vec` class, or is there a way to keep both `Vec.random(n)` as well as `Vec2.random()`?

Additionally, I was trying to move functions like `dot` to the module level, but then wouldn't users have to call both of these imports if they were dotting two `Vec2` vectors:

```
from pyorama.math3d.vec import dot
from pyorama.math3d.vec2 import Vec2
```

I would rather that users not even touch the base `Vec` class at all! Is there a cleaner way to do imports if I switch the `dot` function code to a module level, either by doing some import trickery in the `__init__.py` file in the `math3d` folder where all this code is or in `vec.py` or `vec2.py`?

---

For anyone interested in what the "final" code looks like, I now have completed writing code for the `Vec2/3/4`, `Mat2/3/4`, and `Quat` classes. This can all be found in [this](https://github.com/AnishN/pyorama) github repository under the `math3d` folder. Thanks for all of your feedback and help!

Comment: Is there any specific reason to rewrite this kind of library instead of using numpy for example? It would surely simplify your implementation of quaternions especially if you'll be computing time derivatives of your quaternions.

Comment: @ChrisR I have used numpy before and enjoyed it but it is not as convenient to use in the context of a game. For instance, for a 4x4 matrix, numpy doesn't provide any rotation, lookAt, or perspective methods. Plus it didn't make much sense to make a general numpy array behind the scenes and bring in that overhead when the arrays are so small and numpy's vectorization benefits would not be seen (for a vec2, it is just two items). I am basically trying to recreate something like the glm library for c++ or glmatrix library for javascript.

Comment: I see. But doesn't that mean you'll have a ton of code duplication between your Vec2-4 classes if you don't want to use arrays? The way I would tackle the problem is to use both your custom implementation and numpy: have a super class which generates the correctly sized vector/matrix, and store all the data in a numpy array. Then for anything which isn't supported by numpy, do your own implementation. It also limits the scope of what you need to write tests for.

Comment: @ChrisR The super class approach is definitely the right one in this case! A quick parsing of all of the function names in the glmatrix source shows that there is a lot of overlap. I will go ahead and implement a generic `vec` class tonight along with an extended `vec2` class and update the question. I will also have to figure out how to do x, y, z, and w properties for each of the special cases of the `vec` class. Do you have any advice about the function names and the use/abuse of `@classmethod`?

Comment: Sounds good. Concerning the naming, there is no convention that I know of. Unless the function name will be outrageously long, I'd stick with the full name (so use "distance" instead of "dist"). That way you don't need to read any documentation to know what it's about ("dist" could be a distribution instead of a distance for example). Concerning the class methods, my opinion is that those which return an object of the same class are fine (eg random which returns a vector). The other ones, like dot, should be package functions (they'll be imported the same way: from myvectors import dot).

Comment: Also, I'm slightly confused at your min and max functions: they return the min/max of each component of the vector. Is that your plan? Just from the name of these functions, I would expect them to return the vector with the smallest or greatest absolute value. If the latter is the goal, I would recommend you to overload the operator functions for less than and greater than. That will allow you to use the built-in min and max functions with any number of parameters which are all of the same type.

Comment: @ChrisR I tried making all of your suggested edits to my code and have updated my question with those two classes' code. The process raised some new questions/issues that I would appreciate you looking at if you can!

Comment: Two easy wins: 1) add a `__repr__` method for easy debuggability, and 2) in your constructor, just do `self.x = x` and `self.y = y`, which will call your custom setters. Saves you duplicating that logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version, I don't understand your various

```
if isinstance(self, types):
```

checks. Since you are building the `Vec2` class, you know that `self` is of type `Vec2` or one of its subclasses, if any. So these checks will always evaluate to `False`: you’d better remove them.

But as you figured out with the second version, you can remove a lot of repetitions with a base class or some kind of factory.

However, what seems a big mistake in the second version is the fact that you are downcasting any `VecX` to a `Vec` after the first arithmetic operation. Meaning that

```
v1 = Vec2(4, 8)
v2 = Vec2(1, 1)
v3 = v1 + v2
print(v3.x, v3.y)
```

Will raise `AttributeError` for the `v3.x` and `v3.y` accesses. Because `v3` is a `Vec` and not a `Vec2`.

To avoid that, I don't have any better idea than to hack the `__init__` method a bit:

```
def Vector(n):
    class Vec(object):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            try:
                data, = args
            except ValueError:
                data = np.array(args, dtype=np.float32)
            assert len(data) == n
            self.data = data
        # other common methods
    return Vec

class Vec2(Vector(2)):
    # special methods for Vec2
```

This allows you to call `Vec2(data)` where `data` is a `numpy` array as well as `Vec2(2, 0.8)`.

This means that, in your various operators, you will need to return the right type, something along the lines of `return self.__class__(self.data + other.data)` should do, for the addition.

---

The last thing that I wanted to mention is your usage of the properties. Why manage a separate variable when you have direct access to the underlying data structure? I would simplify `Vec2` to:

```
class Vec2(Vector(2)):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.data[0]

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self.data[0] = value  # No need to manually convert to float, numpy will do it for us

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.data[1]

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self.data[1] = value
```

Comment: Definitely agree with most of what you are saying. The `isinstance` checks in the old version made no sense and there is no point of keeping things like `self._x` floating around in the code when using property decorators. You are right about the downcasting issue, but I will have to think about your solution for a bit. Would it just be possible to modify `Vec` directly rather than introducing `Vector`?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon The only use of the `Vector` "factory" is the ability to `assert len(data) == n`. Some other optimizations may depend on `n`, I don't know. If you don't find any and/or don't need the `assert`, you can safely remove the function in favor of a single base class.

Comment: I think I can eliminate the `Vector` factory. Then in the `Vec2` class, I can override each inherited function by either calling the corresponding parent `Vec` function with `super` and casting the results by returning a `Vec2` object at the end using `return Vec2(*result.data)` or define some custom behavior (which may be useful for say handling transforming matrices of various sizes).

Comment: @CodeSurgeon you don't need to cast (and thus, to override) if you use something like `return self.__class__(self.data + other.data)` instead of `return Vec(self.data + other.data)`

Comment: Doesn't that only work if I keep the `Vec2` and the `Vec` constructors the same? I want to create `Vec2` objects by passing in an x and a y value rather than a numpy array.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon You'll note that I don't define an `__init__` in `Vec2`. `Vec` already handle being passed a single parameter being a `numpy` array or `n` parameters that will be converted to an array.

Comment: Right, forgot to remove my `__init__` from `Vec2`. Fixed that and it works perfectly. Thank you so much!